# Get this path to check if file exists

Tags: android, file, environment

I'm trying to get this internal path: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.d_apps.detonajogos/files/Download/1.txt" to check if a file (1.txt) exists but I can't find a method with Environment to get it.

I downloaded the file with this:

```
downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "1.txt");
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
```

And try to check the file with:

```
File extStore = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            File pdf = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "1.txt");

            if(pdf.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: That is not the same question, anyway I found the solution by myself.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to reach is not accessible with `Environment`. Try [`getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) available in [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) class which gives you your internal app external files directory and then add `/Download/1.txt` to the path.